# Let f be differentiable, prove that there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) + f'(c) = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

Let $f$ be differentiable on $R$ and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.  Prove that there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) + f'(c) = 0 $

Can someone help me with this proof?

Comment: Can we assume that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer differentiable implies continuous

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer, differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: Oh right, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

$$f'(x)+f(x)=e^{-x}\frac d{dx}(e^x f(x)).$$
Maybe Rolle applied to $e^x f(x)$ would help?

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x)=e^xf(x)$. Then $g(0)=g(1)=0$. Apply Mean Value Theorem now.

Comment: I meant that only